Transaction isolation level for moving money
So I have an account entity in Spring JPA and POstgres as DB and I want to move money from one account to another. I'm trying to figure out what's the correct isolation level for such a thing?
@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private double balance;

}

...//Service
    @Transactional
    void createTransaction(double amount, long fromAccountId, long toAccountId) {
        Account fromAccount = repository.findById(fromAccountId);

        Account toAccount = repository.findById(toAccountId);

        if (fromAccount.getBalance() < amount) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        fromAccount.setBalance(fromAccount.getBalance() - amount);
        toAccount.setBalance(toAccount.getBalance() + amount);

        repository.save(fromAccount);
        repository.save(toAccount);

        // Also save from, to, amount and time in a transactions table
    }


}

Now my issue is concurrency when multiple such requests come in? How to tackle those to avoid inconsistent data. Is the default ReadCommitted be okay here? I think only Serializable is probably solve the problem here but I'm not quite sure, or should I just use manual java readwrite locks here for consistency?
My main concern is what happens if I read fromBalance and it was above amount but in the meantime I was updating it another request reduced it, now I'll be in a inconsistent state and should actually throw an exception.
I could even have a complete new request to just getBalance() but I don't think it matters that much, main issue is to make the createTransaction work correctly.

"I think only Serializable is probably solve the problem here" -> Yes, that is the correct one to use. What you need to do, however, is start your transation by a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE so that you get the most up-to-date data + lock it until you commit (or rollback). This means the data you selected is guaranteed to be up-to-date, unmodified by other clients/concurrent connections.

So should I just use  @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
or do something like leave the @Transactional as it is but use the pessimistic  locking in repository @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
Optional findById(Long id);

I'm tempted to take back what I said about the isolation level. ReadCommitted will allow client2 to see what client1 just did even if their respective transactions were active at least partly in the same time. SELECT FOR UPDATE should be all you need to ensure save() works with the up-to-date balance (I am unsure the lock you are describing does that). I do not see a case where you'd write the wrong (based on out of date) data to the DB nor create a deadlock (postgres has protections against them but do not forget to check the status code returned to you after the update).
